# Vuetify Data Tables: Fetch data when expanding a row

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js, expand

I have a Vuetify data table with expandable rows. Each row correlates with a customer's order which consists of samples they want to be tested.

Currently, I'm retrieving all the orders with all the samples but it takes too long to load all the information.

So instead of retrieving all the samples for every order, when I expand a row I want to be able to perform an API call to retrieve the samples that should be displayed in the expanded section for that particular order.

I've researched all I can and have come to a dead-end. Here's where I'm at currently:

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="orders_headers"
  :items="orders"
  show-expand
  :single-expand="true"
  :expanded.sync="expanded"
>

  <!-- Expand Buttons -->
  <template v-slot:item.data-table-expand="{ item, isExpanded, expand }">
    <v-btn @click="expand(true)" v-if="!isExpanded">Expand</v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="expand(false)" v-if="isExpanded">close</v-btn>
  </template>

  <!-- Expanded Data -->
  <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
    <td :colspan="headers.length">

      <table v-for="(sample, index) in item.samples" :key="index">
        <tr>
          <th>Sample Acc</th>
          <td>{{ sample.sample_accession }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sample Status</th>
          <td>{{ sample.sample_status }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

### I think I may have figured it while writing this

As I was typing this out, I realized what I possibly need to do. I need to add a method call to the expand button, then in that method set the results to `expandedSamples` and replace `item.samples` with it.

In the meantime, if anyone has any better solution I'd love to hear. Otherwise, I'll post my solution in case anyone else is trying to attempt something similar to this.

### Bonus

Anyone know if there's a way to tap into the expand event without replacing the default icons/functionality or a way to include the original icons/functionality when using `v-slot:item.data-table-expand`?

Currently when I'm using `v-slot:item.data-table-expand`, I have to add the buttons back in and I lose the chevrons and the animations.

Comment: You're on the right track. You should catch the expand event and fetch the data. Then populate the item.

Comment: Hoping for an answer on the bonus question too. I just want to change the color of the chevron icons but I can't find the original code for what was inside v-slot:item.data-table-expand

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the benefit of future readers facing the same issue, use the `@item-expanded` event of the data-table to lazy load the item details (or child data) on demand. Hook the `item-expanded` event to a method (e.g. loadDetails) that loads the data, and then merges the response into the original items array.

Here's an example...

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  show-expand
  single-expand
  item-key="name"
  :search="search"
  @item-expanded="loadDetails"
>
  <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
    <td :colspan="headers.length">
      <table v-for="(sample, index) in items.samples" :key="index">
        <tr>
          <th>Sample Acc</th>
          <td>{{ sample.sample_accession }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

```js
  methods: {
    loadDetails({item}) {
      axios.get('http.../' + item.id)
        .then(response => {
          item.samples = response.data[0]
        })
    }
  }
```

https://codeply.com/p/d5XibmqjUh

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It calls the method that I hook onto @item-expanded when i open and close the expanded panel. Is there way to only call my method when expanding?

Comment: This should work only when the Row is expanded, it triggers an event for the collapsed row too. Any help.? @frlzjosh

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic solution to my issue.

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="orders_headers"
  :items="orders"
  show-expand
  :single-expand="true"
  :expanded.sync="expanded"
>

  <!-- Expand Buttons -->
  <template v-slot:item.data-table-expand="{ item, isExpanded, expand }">
    <v-btn @click="expand(true); getSamples(item.id)" v-if="!isExpanded">Expand</v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="expand(false)" v-if="isExpanded">close</v-btn>
  </template>

  <!-- Expanded Data -->
  <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
    <td :colspan="headers.length">

      <table v-for="(sample, index) in expandedOrderDetails" :key="index">
        <tr>
          <th>Sample Acc</th>
          <td>{{ sample.sample_accession }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sample Status</th>
          <td>{{ sample.sample_status }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>

<script>
methods: {
  getSamples(orderId) {
    // Perform API call
    this.expandedOrderDetails = response.data;
  },
}
</script>
```

After many hours of development, our project leader has decided he wants each row to correlate to each sample instead of orders though. So expanding is no longer necessary.